# Deploying AllowanceCrowdsale with Chainlink Pricefeed problem

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale, chainlink

I am new to Solidity and lost how i can acomplish to integrate the Chainlink Pricefeed into the OpenZepellin 2.5.0 AllowanceCrowdsale contract.

What i have got so far:

The Crowdsale contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/validation/PausableCrowdsale.sol";

contract Seedround is Crowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, PausableCrowdsale {

  constructor(
    uint256 _rate,
    address payable _wallet,
    ERC20 _token,
    address _tokenWallet
  )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    AllowanceCrowdsale(_tokenWallet)
    public
  {}

}
```

I want to set the swap "rate" based on the BNB price, so i wrote a small contract to fetch the BNB Chainlink pricefeed and calculate the actuall rate based on my desired token sell price.

The Pricefeed contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.5/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract MyRate {
    
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Binance Smart Chain Testnet
     * Aggregator: BNB/USD
     * Address: 0x2514895c72f50D8bd4B4F9b1110F0D6bD2c97526
     */
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x2514895c72f50D8bd4B4F9b1110F0D6bD2c97526);
    }

    function getRate() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        price = price / 10 ** 6; // get BNB price in cents
        price = 1000000000000000000 / price; //calculate amount of BNB wei for one centUSD
        uint256 a = 10000000000000000000/uint256(85); //calculate amount of MyToken wei for one centUSD
        uint256 exchangeRate = a / uint256(price); //calculate _rate for crowdsale
        return int256(exchangeRate);
    }
}
```

Up to here everything is fine and working. Now i tried to merge both contracts and feed the _rate from the pricefeed contract into the `Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)` function and this is where i am stuck.
Beside that the contract probably wont work because i could not test it yet, i can't even get it deployed, it exits with following error message:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
```

The merged contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/validation/PausableCrowdsale.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.5/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Swaplast is Crowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, PausableCrowdsale {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    
    function getCrowdsaleRate() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        price = price / 10 ** 6; // get BNB price in cents
        price = 1000000000000000000 / price; //calculate amount of BNB wei for one centUSD
        uint256 a = 10000000000000000000/uint256(85); //calculate amount of MyToken wei for one centUSD
        uint256 exchangeRate = a / uint256(price); //calculate _rate for crowdsale
        return int256(exchangeRate);
    }

    uint256 myrate = uint256(getCrowdsaleRate());
    
    /**
     * Network: Binance Smart Chain Testnet
     * Aggregator: BNB/USD
     * Address: 0x2514895c72f50D8bd4B4F9b1110F0D6bD2c97526
     */
    constructor(
    uint256 _rate,
    address payable _wallet,
    ERC20 _token,
    address _tokenWallet
  ) 
    
    Crowdsale(myrate, _wallet, _token)
    AllowanceCrowdsale(_tokenWallet)
    public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x2514895c72f50D8bd4B4F9b1110F0D6bD2c97526); 
    }

}
```

So my questions are:

1. why do i get this gas error at deploying?
2. will this work at all or i am totally on the wrong path? and
3. what would be the best way to use the getRate() function to get the "myRate" value into `Crowdsale(myrate, _wallet, _token)` ? Should i deploy the contracts separately and do a remote contract function call to get myRate?

You see i am somewhat lost here;) every input is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the contract's function before the contract itself is deployed. Delete next line

```
uint256 myrate = uint256(getCrowdsaleRate());
```

To get the rate you should probably separate your logic into several smart contracts